# The pictures in my carousel that I am using do not fit the entire screen

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I am using a carousel that I integrated into my website, but the pictures that I have aren't fitting the entire screen. I tried fixing the width, but nothing is changing. My code is below, Plunk here http://plnkr.co/edit/vApBLJCMI6Z7G45qY80e?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="width:5000px">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://coolwildlife.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-3004/Fox%20Picture%20003.jpg" alt="First slide">

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1520/24330829813_944c817720_b.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When possible, include a link to a plunker, fiddle, or similar. I've added one for this question.

Comment: Just because you set the container of the images doesn't automatically mean the images are going to stretch to the width of that container, you need to be setting widths on the images themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `.img-fluid` to `witdth: 100%` or `width: inherit`. Then slider would be full width.

```css
.img-fluid{
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://coolwildlife.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-3004/Fox%20Picture%20003.jpg" alt="First slide">

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1520/24330829813_944c817720_b.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a plunker for the above code http://plnkr.co/edit/EYf65WtH8nVh9Pwzyxl1?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for this, one question I don't see the dot indicators anymore to choose the image

Comment: I accidentally removed it, if you add them back it would still work the same.

Comment: Ok, I also noticed that when the next photo slides in the height changes really weirdly, like when the 1st photo goes to the 2nd photo I see white space and then the image resizes.

Comment: Height is set to auto, so it's adjusting height based on width, it would be best if you use images with similar width and height.

Comment: I changed the height so I was able to fix it. Thank you for this.

Comment: Great, happy to help, please select as correct answer if my answer helped you.